# Justify and center text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, article

I would like to justify and center text in the following manner:

[image: example]

Notice how each line is exactly the same length. How is this done?

I am using a documentclass article and no packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
jajasdjsdjsd sdj asj
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

or you could use

```
\begin{quotation}
jajasdjsdjsd sdj asj
\end{quotation}
```

(which allows page breaking)

or you could use

```
\begin{abstract}
jajasdjsdjsd sdj asj
\end{abstract}
```

which is more or less the same, but writes  **abstract** at the start.

Answer (score 2):

> Notice how **each line is exactly the same length**.

Surely you want only a narrower paragraph, but as you asked for it, this solution  produce the same length *also in the last line* using to `\parfillskip` and `\emergencystretch`. The rest of the obfuscated TeX code is just to be outlandish and not use a simple  LaTeX environment (Disclaimer: except for a abstract-like simple paragraph this could produce unexpected problems).

The use of `microtype` package is optional (if you are tolerant to very bad spacing).

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
%dummy text
\def\blablabla{%
\textbf{Abstract}. nano  is  a small, free and friendly editor 
which aims to replace Pico,  the default editor included in the 
non-free Pine package.  Rather than  just  copying  Pico's  look
and feel, nano also implements some missing (or disabled by 
default) features in Pico, such as ``search and replace''  and 
``go to line and column number''.}

\parskip1em
\begin{document}

\blablabla

{\hsize.5\linewidth\hfill\vbox{\parfillskip0pt%
\emergencystretch.5\linewidth\noindent\blablabla}\hfill}     

\blablabla

\end{document}
```